# Maze Problem. Getting adjacent cells from starting point in Matrix

Tags: c, matrix, breadth-first-search, adjacency-list

From my starting point 's' I am trying to get the adjacent coordinates cells and add (x,y) points into my Queue. I have issues on how I am able to retrieve the adjacent cells.

I have created a linked list for each row which indicates the free spaces that are valid and adjacent to each node. However, I have been stuck on how I can coordinate each space and consider it as adjacent to my current or starting point.

Here is my function that creates my 2d matrix:

```
   void CreateGrid(char* filename, FILE* fp, int rowCount, int colNum)
{
    int i, j;
    int cords[2];
    struct queue* q = createQueue();



     int dimensions[rowCount][colNum];
        for (i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {

             for (j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {
                    char brick = getc(fp);
                  dimensions[i][j] = brick;


                  if (brick == 's'){
                       cords[0] = i;
                       cords[1] = j;//Starting Point
                       enqueue_pair(q, cords); //Queue has: (3,10), 
                  }



printf("%c", dimensions[i][j]);

        }
    }

        printQueue(q);
         fclose(fp); //close file
         fp = fopen(filename, "r");   //reopen
        solve(fp, int cord[0], int cord[1],colNum, rowCount); //where I use Linked list

}
```

Here is where I use the Linked list to get each space by each row:

```
    void solve(FILE* fp,int xstart, int ystart, int colNum, int rowCount)
{
     int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            deleteAll(); //function that deletes Linked List at start of NEW ROW

             for (j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {
                 char graphNode = getc(fp);

                 if (graphNode == ' '){
                     add(NULL); //null value set to zero
                     append(j); //appends front of Linked List
                     delete(0); //removes null 0 value

                 }
             }
            printf("\nRow [%d] -> ", i);
            disp(); //displays linked list

  }

}
```

Here is how I implement my Linked List:

```
 //Linked List implementation

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} *head, *temp, *curr, *left;

void add(int num) {
        int i=0;
        temp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->data = num;

            if(head == NULL) {
                head = temp;
                head->next = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                temp->next = head;                
                head = temp;
            }

    }
void append(int data) {

        temp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->data = data;
        curr = head;

        if(curr == NULL) {
            head = temp; 
            head->next = NULL;
        }

        while(curr->next != NULL) {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = temp;
        curr = temp;
        curr->next = NULL;
    }
```

Lastly, Here is my output so far:

```
bbbbbb bbbbbbb                                                                                              
bb         bbb                                                                                              
bb b bbbbbbbbb                                                                                              
bb b      sbbb                                                                                              
bb bbbbbbbbbbb                                                                                              
bb     b   bbb                                                                                              
bbbbbb b b bbb                                                                                              
bb  b    b bbb                                                                                              
bbbbbbbbbbbbbb��                                                                                            
Queue Contains: (3,10)                                                                                      

Row [0] -> 6 ->                                                                                             
Row [1] -> 2 ->  3 ->  4 ->  5 ->  6 ->  7 ->  8 ->  9 ->  10 ->                                            
Row [2] -> 2 ->  4 ->                                                                                       
Row [3] -> 2 ->  4 ->  5 ->  6 ->  7 ->  8 ->  9 ->                                                         
Row [4] -> 2 ->                                                                                             
Row [5] -> 2 ->  3 ->  4 ->  5 ->  6 ->  8 ->  9 ->  10 ->                                                  
Row [6] -> 6 ->  8 ->  10 ->                                                                                
Row [7] -> 2 ->  3 ->  5 ->  6 ->  7 ->  8 ->  10 ->                                                        
Row [8] -> Link list is empty
```

**Expectation:
Queue to visit every adjacent node so
Queue has:
(3,10), (3,9), (3,8)...**

Algorithm visits every space except the walls that contain 'b' and the exit on the TOP row.

EXPECTED OUTPUT --> the 'b' are replaced by -1.  0 is starting point. integers are incrementing

```
 -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   11   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1 
  -1   -1   10    9    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   -1   -1   -1   -1 
  -1   -1   11   -1    7   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1 
  -1   -1   12   -1    6    5    4    3    2    1    0   -1   -1   -1   -1 
  -1   -1   13   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1 
  -1   -1   14   15   16   17   18   -1   24   25   26   -1   -1   -1   -1 
  -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   19   -1   23   -1   27   -1   -1   -1   -1 
  -1   -1  136  136   -1   21   20   21   22   -1   28   -1   -1   -1   -1 
  -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
```

Comment: What is your expected output, and how is it different from the actual output?

Comment: Well,  the problem goes like this... we start at position 's' on the matrix which is on cord (3,10). The algorithm (BFS) states that we need to get the nodes (or spaces) that are adjacent to the current or starting point, getting you the shortest path to the exit.   I read that I needed to convert my matrix into an adjanceny list (linked list that contains all the nodes that are ''connected').  So, right now I have a linked list that gives just that (I hope) and now I need to actually implement the algorithim (BFS) to get the shortest path.  So the idea is to continue adding the adjacent node

Comment: into my queue and essentially keeping track of each step.  I have issues on retrieving these adjacent nodes (or spaces) and pushing them into my queue.

Comment: Again, unless you edit your question to show what you want your expected output to be, we cannot begin to guess what these "issues" are.

Comment: @bk_32 okay. i edited the question and gave the expected output of the algorithm I have trouble implementing.

Comment: You can use a simple `getNeighbors` method. See such method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54999615/3992939)